# mysql syntax error when select from database cart

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

I have an error in my syntax and I cant find it.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN']))
{
    $custsql = "SELECT id, status from orders WHERE customer_id = ". 
    $_SESSION['SESS_USERID']. " AND status < 2;";
    $custres = mysql_query($custsql)or die(mysql_error());
    $custrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($custres);

    $itemssql = "SELECT products.*, orderitems.*, orderitems.id AS itemid FROM 
    products, orderitems WHERE orderitems.product_id =products.id AND order_id = " . $custrow['id'];
    $itemsres = mysql_query($itemssql)or die(mysql_error());;
    $itemnumrows = mysql_num_rows($itemsres);
}
```

I get the error on $itemssql .

Comment: . $custrow['id']; there is a dot here is this right

Comment: yes it is a dot

Comment: It is a PHP error or mysql error? What do you get?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''

Comment: I just echo something before and after $itemssql to see where is the problem and i noticed that i have only the before echo ..

Comment: You should try and move away from mysql_ functions and especially when not using prepared statements and bind variables.  You also do no checking that any of your stages has actually worked.  Each `query` or `fetch` should check if there is actually anything to work with.